# Is it possible to have a 200% CTR in Adwords?

Tags: google, google-search, google-adsense, google-ads

For one impression, My Adword campaigning is having 2 clicks how is it possible ?

[image]

Many times, I feel Adword is over charging the customer like this.

Answer (score 2):

Every click must have an impression, but the click and the impression don't have to happen on the same day.

- 11:59 PM Jan 1st -- User views your ad
- 12:01 AM Jan 2nd -- User clicks on the ad

You will have 1 click with 0 impressions on Jan 2nd (and 1 impressions with 0 clicks on Jan 1st.)

Comment: I do not run my ads on night time. My Ads starts at 7 AM and ends at 11 PM.

Comment: There is no reason somebody couldn't leave a page with an ad on it open and click on it later.   And when you say overnight, what time zone is that?   I believe that all reporting in AdWords in US Pacific time zone where Google is located.

Comment: Time zone : IST (Indian Std Time)

Comment: Midnight Pacific time when the reports roll over to a new day is 1:30 PM India standard time.  You are running ads then.